# Allow from ip works in one domain not in others

Tags: .htaccess

in htaccess i have

```
order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

which blocks all ip address to site. after that there is:

```
allow from 123.456.789.098
```

so, if i will try to access site using 123.456.789.098 ip then it works, for other ips it is blocked. But problem is that this works just in .com domain.(there is actually many domains) it doesn't work for .de .fr .eu and others. but all domains uses same hosting and looks to same .htaccess. when i remove `Deny from all` then it works for all domains. What can be reason for this? May be serverside problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you change to:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 123.456.789.098
Deny from all
```

something change? Surely all domains have a common .htaccess file?